# Are some TLDs more expensive than others?

Tags: domain-registrar, top-level-domains, pricing

The registration price for domains containing "hot" keyphrases in a *domain name* (such as `seo`) is often automatically higher as these considered premium by a pricing algorithm (and its developers).

I wouldn't be surprised if some top level domains (TLDs) will be priced in a similar way; for example, a domain with a TLD like `.org` might automatically be priced higher than, I don't know, maybe, `.info`.

Is there a similar pricing process for TLDs and what could be a good example from some formal literature?

Answer (score 2):

Each registry is free to sell its domain the way it wishes, and some do premiums, some do not.
Although it is a very broad subject, it seems to me it is quite covered in passages containing the word `premium` here:

- [How to ensure I always buy an informative domain in the lowest price possible?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/126900/how-to-ensure-i-always-buy-an-informative-domain-in-the-lowest-price-possible) or
- [Should renewal price of gTLD will always be identical to the price of purchase?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/126880/should-renewal-price-of-gtld-will-always-be-identical-to-the-price-of-purchase)

Also, maybe this older but extensive answer from me on a similar question would help: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/119904/75842 ("Why TLD domains cost different amounts")

> for example, a domain with a TLD like .org might automatically be priced higher than, I don't know, maybe, .info.

Each registry is independent, so they chose their prices based on their own internal policies, so yes at some given point in time, a `.org` may cost more than a `.info`, and then later if registries change their prices, the situation can be the opposite.
But there is nothing really to answer here: prices change in both time and space (accross TLDs/registries).
Some names are even free (with caveats), see `.tk` for example.

> Is there a similar pricing process for TLDs(?)

There are few things similar between pricing domain names and pricing TLDs:
Technically they all work the same, but for anything non technical like prices, there is a lot of diversity.

> what could be a good example from some formal literature?

I am not sure to understand what kind of literature you are searching for:
 Policies might be different for each TLD. In gTLDs, you have ICANN rules and contracts. They have mention of prices, like I said in my response to one of your previous question linked at start:

> There are no real user-visible differences besides the underlying
>   contracts as explained above. You can read ICANN master contract with
>   registries (the 2012 batch, the legacy ones like com, net, org, etc.
>   have their own specific contract) at
>   https://newgtlds.icann.org/sites/default/files/agreements/agreement-approved-31jul17-en.html
>   About pricing, look specifically at section §2.10.

Comment: Hello, I have suggested an edit of minor phrasing changes, markdown, `<br>` and one passage edit per clarification in question.

Comment: I thank you for the answer --- Maybe due to longevity of previous answers and some cognitive bias at the time (due to hard period) I missed something.